# (This widget has been unmounted, so the State no longer has a context (and should be considered defunct)

Tags: flutter

In initState() method I'm calling one method name 'getProductsData'. In this method I'm calling Provider's method and because it's an async method, I've loading spinner on going on the screen, then once I get the return value from Provider's method, I'm changing state, so that my loader will stop and other widget will shown on the screen. on the very first fresh app started, I'm facing this following issue.

FlutterError (This widget has been unmounted, so the State no longer has a context (and should be considered defunct).
Consider canceling any active work during "dispose" or using the "mounted" getter to determine if the State is still active.)

following is my code, even though I've added mounted in the condition, I'm facing problem.

```
@override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    // _buildContext = context;
    // _productsProvider = Provider.of<Products>(context, listen: false);
    getProductsData();
    textController = TextEditingController();
    SchedulerBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
      String otpMessage =
          Provider.of<Auth>(context, listen: false).userRegMessage;
      if (otpMessage.isNotEmpty) {
        GlobalSnackBar.show(context, otpMessage);
      }
      Provider.of<Auth>(context, listen: false).userRegMessage = "";
    });
 
  }

  Future<void> getProductsData() async {
    if(mounted){
      await Provider.of<Products>(context, listen: false).getProductsData();
      products = Provider.of<Products>(context, listen: false).productDataList;
      setState(() {
        productDataLoading = false;
      });
    }
   

  }
```

Comment: add setState inside if(mounted){}

Comment: I would maybe do another `if (mounted)` check after the `await`. Who knows how long that await takes. By the time it's finished it might not be mounted anymore

Comment: In general, you should avoid calling async functions from `initState`. I would recommend using a `FutureBuilder` for scenarios like this.